# How much extra gas does a single storage constant add to a contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, gas, storage

I am considering adding a storage var to my Solidity contract that would represent the "version" that that contract has.

However, I am not sure that the added gas cost warrants that. How much extra gas does a single storage constant add to the deployment cost?

Say that the constant is of type `uint256`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's find out the answer empirically, with [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org). Take this contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity >=0.8.9;

contract SingleConstant {
    uint256 internal foo;
    
    function getFoo() external view returns (uint256) {
        return foo;
    }
    
    function getFoo(uint256 newFoo) external {
        foo = newFoo;
    }
}
```

With the compiler version 0.8.9 and the optimizer set to 200 runs, it cost [90,551 gas](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x887bce6d15e1888403372fa9f1e8afcd808a0259503afdff01bccde50e37dc33) to deploy the contract.

Now, after adding the constant:

```
uint256 public constant version = 1;
```

It cost [94,443 gas](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x0bc3f8db3de71bbf4f501bac535828cc3bc32a4b1d49be6ba770eb8a72d69a1d) to make the deployment. Thus the extra gas needed to store a single uint256 constant is 94,443 - 90,551 = 3,892. That should be a reasonable price to pay for the added clarity of using a versioning system.

Note that the gas cost depends on the value of `version`. The higher the numerical value, the higher gas price, though the cost should grow linearly. E.g. for setting `version` to 3141592653589793238 (PI multiplied by 10^18), the gas cost [rose](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xb04a367564df8a7a072074d6a763f75f486325300b62dc11c47db20fab72f323) to 95,961.